# Enterprisedb, PostgreSQL cast to date

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, enterprisedb

How to cast **'2015-11-13 00:00:00'** (*text or timestamp*) to **'2015-11-13'**(*date*) in Enterprisedb (EDB) ?

With 4 queries below:

```
1/ SELECT '2015-11-13 00:00:00'::date ; --> result: "2015-11-13" 
2/ SELECT date ( '2015-11-13 00:00:00' ) ;
3/ SELECT cast ( '2015-11-13 00:00:00' as date) ;
4/ SELECT to_char('2015-11-13 00:00:00'::timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd'::text);
```

In EDB 9.3 , just one query no.4 can cast. And PG 9.3 , all queries can do.

Are there still any ways to cast date in EDB ?

**EDIT**:
With EDB :

```
    1/ SELECT '2015-11-13 00:00:00'::date ; --> result: "2015-11-13 00:00:00" 
    2/ SELECT date ( '2015-11-13 00:00:00' ) ; --> result: "2015-11-13 00:00:00" 
    3/ SELECT cast ( '2015-11-13 00:00:00' as date) ; --> result: "2015-11-13 00:00:00"  
    4/ SELECT to_char('2015-11-13 00:00:00'::timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd'::text);  --> result: "2015-11-13"
```

Comment: All of them should work in EnterpriseDB. What exactly is the error you get?

Comment: I will clarify my post .  With Enterpriseb, only the query number 4 (select to_char....)  can work as I wish. I do not know why query number 1 can not cast.     I think , EDB do not have "date" data type.

Comment: EDB tries to be Oracle compatible, and in Oracle a `DATE` contains a time part, maybe that's the reason. If that is, you need to check if you can disable the Oracle compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Check the server's redwood date setting:

`show edb_redwood_date`

If set to 'on' it includes times as part of dates, if set to 'off' it does not.

Change the setting with:

```
alter system set edb_redwood_date=off;
select pg_reload_conf();
```

See: [enterpriseDB.com Docs - edb_redwood_date](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/epas/latest/epas_compat_ora_dev_guide/01_introduction/01_edb_redwood_date/)